# Which episodes of the Slam Dunk anime correspond to which manga chapters?

Tags: slam-dunk

I enjoy watching anime episodes based on the manga chapters I read. I couldn't find any source on exactly which Slam Dunk episodes are based on which chapters?

Comment: did you go to wikipedia?

Comment: Yes. I wouldn't be asking here is it was on wikipedia or the wiki.